# NX bit emulation

Tags: operating-system, bit, buffer-overflow

Could someone explain to me how the NX bit can be emulated on platforms such as 32-bit x86 where the hardware doesn't provide it? I would be greatful for an explanation of the basics of the way it is emulated since I simply can't imagine how it could be realized. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to read about [Exec Shield](http://people.redhat.com/mingo/exec-shield/docs/WHP0006US_Execshield.pdf), [PaX PAGEEXEC](http://pax.grsecurity.net/docs/pageexec.txt) and [PaX SEGMEXEC](http://pax.grsecurity.net/docs/segmexec.txt).

Answer (score 0):

I've never implemented NX emulation, but knowing something about x86 here's my best guess of how it can work.

It all has to do with how the kernel sets up your [global descriptor table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Descriptor_Table) to define what range of addresses may contain code.

If I may summarize it inelegantly...  On x86 in 32-bit protected mode, those old "segment registers" from 16-bit code still have some meaning.  The segment registers determine which entry in the [GDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Descriptor_Table) is used.  The GDT entries are essentially a memory range.  If the kernel points the `cs` (code segment) register at a GDT entry that only has addresses in range [x, y], then addresses outside that range are non-executable.

Note that this is much more coarse-grain than an NX bit, because the NX bit goes in the [page table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table) entry.  So the NX bit lets you mark an arbitrary page as non-executable, whereas using `cs` segments only let you specify a (usually vary large, contiguous) range as non-executable.